# How to install USA International keyboard option on Ubuntu Gnome 16.10

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout

I frequently need to use accented letters and for years have used the USA International keyboard for this option. So I was disappointed to find that Ubuntu Gnome no longer includes this as an option when selecting keyboard layouts.

This morning I need to write an email in Spanish and discovered that the very long list of keyboard layouts available in Ubuntu 16.10 does not include the USA International keyboard.

Does anyone know a work-around for the unavailability of the USA International keyboard?

Comment: Sure it's there. It's named _English (US, international with dead keys)_.

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson Under Settings>Personal>Region&Language>Input Sources there are 18 English options including English US.  What I did not understand is that one must click on English US to see additional options under that category. That is where the USA international option is. Thank you for making me investigate further. I felt certain that the answer was well hidden.

Comment: Sounds like GNOME's UI. Anyway, I'm glad you found it at last. :)

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson Yes, it is Gnome. So I guess my answer applies only to Gnome. Thank you. I did not know it was different from regular Ubuntu. I will add that information to the answer I posted.

Comment: Same for LXDE, which I guess uses the Gnome keyboard handler?

Answer (score 47):

Adding a new keyboard option to Ubuntu Gnome is not very intuitive and can be rather frustrating for that reason.

For example, one does not add a keyboard under System Settings > Keyboard.

Instead the option is located under System Settings > Personal > Region & Language > Input Sources > +

When one clicks the + sign one will see a list of languages and this is where some confusion and frustration may ensue: This is NOT a list of keyboard options, so do not peruse this rather lengthy list looking for your desired keyboard option.

Instead, click on the **language** you want. When you do that a **new** list will appear containing the list of **keyboards** available for that language.

From that list click your selection then click the **Add** button.

Comment: My God, that is an unforgivably awful user interface design.

Comment: @James Yes, I agree.