# Does Linux have a US international keyboard layout exactly like the windows version?

Tags: windows, keyboard-layout, dead-keys

Given the huge number of keyboard layouts Ubuntu Linux offers for multiple languages, is there a US international keyboard layout **exactly** like the windows version?

For instance, in the Windows version, I get a `Ç` when I input `'` + `C`.
I know there are ways to get this specific behavior, but they are much more complex than just installing another keyboard (and, in my case, they tend to stop working after major OS upgrades).

So, I am curious: If there are hundreds (or thousands) of Ubuntu keyboard layouts available, why not one for such a popular layout (used by Windows users from several languages on US keyboards)?

Is there any reason why Ubuntu does not offer this particular keyboard layout in Settings/Region & Language/Input Sources options (maybe some sort of copyright restriction)?

Comment: See [how to add US international keyboard in Windows 10](https://thegeekpage.com/how-to-add-us-international-keyboard-in-windows-10/).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to install USA International keyboard option on Ubuntu Gnome 16.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/875688/how-to-install-usa-international-keyboard-option-on-ubuntu-gnome-16-10)

Comment: Hey, close voters. That question does not help to answer the OP's question in any way.

Comment: @User24601 I changed my question to highlight that I am not asking a fix for the cedilla problem. But I would like to know if this keyboard layout exists somewhere or (if it doesn't exist) if there is some problem (maybe legal or technical) that blocks its availability.

Comment: @dilvan: In the answer I submitted I gave you one reason: There are technical barriers on Linux which prevent doing the `ccedilla` thing via an XKB layout. The second reason is probably: Because nobody found it worth it to design such a layout. (AFAIU the _English (US, intl., with dead keys)_ layout is close enough.)

Answer (score 3):

The ability to type `ccedilla` the way you want isn't present via keyboard layouts in Linux. But there is another way:

- Create an `~/.XCompose` file
- Give it this contents:

  ```
  <dead_acute> <C> : "Ç" Ccedilla # LATIN CAPITAL LETTER C WITH CEDILLA
  <dead_acute> <c> : "ç" ccedilla # LATIN SMALL LETTER C WITH CEDILLA
  ```
- Log out and log in again